# JQuery loop each <td> in <tr>

Tags: jquery

I Have the JQuery code below. Basically trying to find the empty string in a td tag and add css to the tr tag, but it adds css to ALL rows not the row that has the empty string. Thank you in advance.

```
$('#mytable > tbody  > tr').each(function(){  
    var $nthis = $(this);

    $('td:first-child').each(function() {
        var $firsttd = $(this);
        console.log($firsttd.text());
    });

//back in the <tr> level
if ($firsttd.text() == "")
    $nthis.css('border-top','solid 2px blue'); 

}); //end of main func
```

Comment: thank you for your responses, i should have been clearer. each td tag contains an input tag. so i don't think i can use :empty, also not strictly the first td i'm looking for, any td in the tr that has .text() == ""

Comment: sorry i meant im looking for the FIRST td in the tr that has .text() == "" but for all rows

Answer (score 2):

Try this : iterate first `td` of each `tr` and check if `text()` is empty. If empty then goto `tr` using `parent()` and change css.

```
$('#mytable > tbody  > tr td:first-child').each(function(){  
//check if td having empty text
if ($(this).text().trim() == "")
   {
    //get parent of td and put css
    $(this).parent().css('border-top','solid 2px blue'); 
   }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6co2anco/10/)**

Comment: I think he wants `:first-child`, not `:first` :)

Comment: `:first-child` means first child of parent, see [this](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and `:first` do the same

Comment: Well, I think he tried to add a border to each `tr` that has it's first `td` empty, not only to the first `tr`. His question is ambigious. Using `:first` adds only one border, using `:first-child` adds as many borders as there are empty first `td`s.

Comment: your right Cristy, i want to check the first td in the tr, but for all rows

Comment: @Cristy and Shyamo, yes you are rigth `:first` will pick only first `td` and not the first `td` of each `tr`. I have updated my answer, please check. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `:first-child` CSS3 selector to get the first `td`, and then `:empty` CSS3 selector to only retrieve the empty `td`s.

```
$(function () {
    $('#mytable > tbody  > tr td:first-child:empty').each(function(){  
        $(this).parent().css('border-top','solid 2px blue');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7n20ast0/

You can make it even shorter by removing the `each` loop:

```
$('#mytable > tbody  > tr td:first-child:empty')
        .parent().css('border-top','solid 2px blue');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7n20ast0/1/

Answer (score 0):

there is a jquery pseudo selector for empty elements:

```
$('#mytable > tbody > tr').find('td:first-child:empty').each(function(){  
var $nthis = $(this).parent();

$nthis.css('border-top','solid 2px blue'); 

}); //end of main func
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if ($firsttd.text() == "")
    $(this).parent().css('border-top','solid 2px blue');
```